# Script for pwdlastset password on python

Tags: python, powershell

Hello I am looking for a script in python that when after I connect to active directory it will reset the value of of pwdlastset to 0 and then to 1 when I do it on a user.

Just like in powershell

```
$User =Get-ADUser xxxxx
$User.pwdlastset = 0
Set-ADUser -Instance $User
$user.pwdlastset = -1
Set-ADUser -instance $User
```

I need something that does the same but in Python

Tried to see many tutorials and explenations but did not find something good.

this is the code:

```
enter code here

server_address = 'xxxx'  
username = 'xxxx'  
password = 'xxxx'   

server = Server(server_address, get_info='ALL')

conn = Connection(server, user=username, password=password, 
auto_bind=True)

if conn.bind():
print('Successfully connected to Active Directory')
else:
print('Failed to connect to Active Directory:', conn.result)
```

Comment: Can you detail what made the resources you already found "not good"? Just so we don't suggest the same :)

Comment: Mainly on youtube and sub forums.

For now I am only able to connect to AD via python but not more than that.

Comment: Please post your code then :)

Comment: Please [update your post](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/76662440/edit) and add the code there (easier to format) :)